# Presenting long string literals (URLs) in Python

Tags: python, url

I have a web scraping application that contains long string literals for the URLs. What would be the best way to present them (keeping in mind that I would like to adhere to [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length).

```
URL = "https://www.targetwebsite.co.foo/bar-app/abc/hello/world/AndThen?whatever=123&this=456&theother=789&youget=the_idea"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(URL)
```

I had thought to do this:

```
URL_BASE = "https://www.targetwebsite.co.foo/"
URL_SUFFIX = "bar-app/abc/hello/world/AndThen"
URL_ARGUMENTS = "?whatever=123&this=456&theother=789&youget=the_idea"
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(URL_BASE + URL_SUFFIX + URL_ARGUMENTS)
```

But there are many lines and it's not a standard way of representing a URL.

Comment: I would put the URLS in a config file, or take them as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

You could use continuation lines with `\`, but it messes the indentation:

```
URL = 'https://www.targetwebsite.co.foo/\
bar-app/abc/hello/world/AndThen\
?whatever=123&this=456&theother=789&youget=the_idea'
```

Or you could use the fact that string literals next to each other are automatically concatenated, in either of these two forms:

```
URL = ('https://www.targetwebsite.co.foo/'
       'bar-app/abc/hello/world/AndThen'
       '?whatever=123&this=456&theother=789&youget=the_idea')

URL = 'https://www.targetwebsite.co.foo/' \
      'bar-app/abc/hello/world/AndThen' \
      '?whatever=123&this=456&theother=789&youget=the_idea'
```

I often use the parenthesized version, but the backslashed one probably looks cleaner.